# How to assign a sepecifc action to the ("Cancel") button within (JOptionPane.showInputDialog) in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane

Here is my question with a short sample code:

```
 double num = 0.00;

try
{
    num = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your num:"));

}

catch (Exception e)
{
    System.err.println("Error: Invalid Input!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid Input!",  
    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

//Validate the num

if (num > 0.0 && num <= 1000.00)
{
    functionA();
}

else if (deposit <= 0.0 || deposit > 1000.00)
{
 System.err.println("Error: out of range");
}
```

*The Problem with the above code is that when i click the "cancel" button, the program is hitting both errors: (the out of range and the invalid input).

Please any suggestions how i can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to verify if the input is null. If not, then you use parseDouble on it.

Like this:

```
try
{
    String i = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your num:");
    if (i != null)
        num = Double.parseDouble(i);
}
```

Also, try to not catch exceptions by putting "Exception", like you did. Always try to specify the exception you are looking for as much as possible.
In this case, you should use NumberFormatException instead of just Exception.

```
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    System.err.println("Error: Invalid Input!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid Input!",  
    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: While these suggestions fix the problem of the user hitting cancel they don't fix the issue of the user getting an out of range warming for pressing cancel or after catching a number format exception. May I suggest moving the validation code into the if statement within the try block.

Answer (score 1):

```
package org.life.java.so.questions;

import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class InputDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Input:");
        if(input == null){
            System.out.println("Calcel presed");
        }else{
            System.out.println("OK presed");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I like seeing complete code examples.  Yours are particularly fine.  But could I make a "Citizen's Request"?  Remove the redundant lines.  The 4 at the top are nonsensical outside the IDE.  The 2nd line of the second comment adds nothing.  The 2 blank lines at the end of main also add no value.  Removing those lines would shorten the E.G. from 26 to just 19 lines - a vertical saving of around 25%. This may not be relevant to people with large monitors, but for us using older monitors with smaller resolutions, it is easier to see the entire example in a single screen. Thanks for considering it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  Considered :)