# how to check if user has input something or not in JDialogBox?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have created a custom dialog box which requires 3 fields

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        JTextField firstName = new JTextField();

        JTextField lastName = new JTextField();

        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();

        final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[] {

                        new JLabel("First"),

                        firstName,

                        new JLabel("Last"),

                        lastName,

                        new JLabel("Password"),

                        password

        };

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputs, "My custom dialog",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println("You entered " +firstName.getText() + ", " +lastName.getText() + ", " +password.getText());

    }
}
```

How do I check if the user has inserted all fields or not? And even if user close the dialog box it display

```
You entered , ,
```

I want to check user input in field and close application if user close dialog box without dsplaying

```
"You entered , , "
```

Comment: why not perform a `null` check on those fields and if any of those 3 fields are null, display the dialog again, indicating that all fields are required.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608124/how-to-assign-a-sepecifc-action-to-the-cancel-button-within-joptionpane-show

Comment: thanks i get it... but what about close operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if user has inserted all fields or not as follows:

```
if(firstName.getText() != "" && lastName.getText() != "" && password.getText() != "")
    System.out.println("All fields have been filled!");
else
    System.out.println("Some fields are need to be filled!");
```

**EDIT:**

For displaying a message after closing the dialog box, you can do it like:

```
myframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered " + firstName.getText() + ", " + lastName.getText() + ", " +password.getText());
    }
});
```

**EDIT2:**

OK, I think I understand your question now, try this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
        JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[]
        {
            new JLabel("First"),
            firstName,
            new JLabel("Last"),
            lastName,
            new JLabel("Password"),
            password        
        };
        int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputs, "My custom dialog",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if(i == 0) System.out.println("You entered " + firstName.getText() + ", " + lastName.getText() + ", " + password.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: @mre: At least, this is what I understand form the OP

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, how does one add a window listener to a `JOptionPane` dialog?

Comment: i think u didnt get my question i want to add window listener to JOptionPane not on JFrame

Comment: @saanu Updated. I hope I understand your question well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach of delimiting each datum.

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
        JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[] {
                new JLabel("First"),
                firstName,
                new JLabel("Last"),
                lastName,
                new JLabel("Password"),
                password
        };

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputs, "My custom dialog",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println("You entered '" +
            firstName.getText() + "', '" +
            lastName.getText() + "', '" +
             //don't ignore deprecation warnings!
            new String(password.getPassword()) + "'.");
    }
}
```

That way, you can tell which field(s) is missing in.

```
You entered '', 'johnson', ''.
You entered 'john', '', ''.
You entered '', '', 'johnsjohnson'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, check to see if there is anything left in the String before print.

```
if(firstName.getText().equals("")) {
    //Respond appropriately to empty string
} else {
    // Respond appropriately to non-empty string
}
```